# For every $y\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $x\in \mathbb{C}^n\setminus \{0\}$ exists a linear map $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $f(x)=y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following statement true?

> For every $y\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $x\in \mathbb{C}^n\setminus \{0\}$, there
>   exists a linear map $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ such that
>   $f(x)=y$.

If yes, how to define $f$? I could imagine to use the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ to define $f$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $S=\{x\}$ and extend it to a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$, $S=\{x, a_2,..., a_n\}$
define $f(x)=y$ and $f(a_i)=a_i$ for $i=2, 3,..,n$

You know that for define a linear map it is enough to know how it operates on base of space.